# Experiments on downward causation due to higher order configurations

Tags: forces, experimental-physics, experimental-technique

Are there any experiments done to verify the absence of forces caused by complex structural organisations in systems? Afaik, experiments in QM and Standard model QFT talk about the validity of the interactions in individual particles that are not in any complex sturctures.

Experiments in Condensed matter physics involve configurations with some structure. In these cases, there is no requirement of downward causation. Are there any experiments in more complex organizations which rule out downward causation? Is it even practically possible at our current experimental strength?